# After loading a jasper report it is possible to retrieve the subreports at runtime

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a report developed in jasper report. It contains several subreports. I need to get the subreport reference to dynamically read the field list of each subreport and the field types. Can anyone help?

I can already read the main dataset and the fields but I haven't been able to read the subreports yet, nor the means to do so. They can point to a link that gives a clue to the solution to the problem.